# Additional parameters in Spring Security Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have managed the login function in my application with Spring Security. I'm doing that with the two default parameters (username and password) and it's work properly.
However, I need to add an extra parameter in the login function, but I'm having problems doing that.

In SecurityConfig.java, I have added the filter and it's calling when submit button is pressed.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/index","/login","/work", "/css/**","/out/**", "/js/**","/images/**","/fonts/**").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll().and()
            .csrf().disable();

            http.addFilterBefore(new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
}
```

Then, my own filter. I'm getting the new parameter(Company) value properly:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

    String dbValue = request.getParameter("Company");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("dbValue", dbValue);

    return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
}
```

I'm having the problem when super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); is called, I'm getting null pointer.

```
Error: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    es.smt.startrekweb.filter.ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

This is the code where I'm having the null pointer in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java

```
 return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
```

Also, I can see in my debugger the next information

```
contextBeforeChainExecution = {SecurityContextImpl@5989} "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication"
authentication = null
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a filter by using new :

```
new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
```

so it does not have anything autowired.
that makes the this.getAuthenticationManager() return null.

if all you need is to pass the request parameter to an attribute - you don't need to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

Note that you only add a filter and did not replace it.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the comment about the filter. But if I don't extend the filter, how could I get the extra information? Because Spring Securty only save username and password by default

Comment: you can extend the filter , but instead of doing new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() , create a bean for it and use it.

Comment: Thanks! I did as you say. I added a filter as a bean instead of a new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() and it works!