# How make Spring security formLogin() use custom filter

Tags: spring-security

I had been trying to make exactly what one  member already did here [Additional parameters in Spring Security Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796157/additional-parameters-in-spring-security-login), but in my case I can't make that the form authentication use the filter :
(I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7)

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                            .and()                              
                            .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
                                        .usernameParameter("username")
                                    .passwordParameter("password").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/").failureUrl("/error.html")                             
                            .and()                              
                            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.addFilterBefore(new WebAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Pass always directly to the UserDetailsService implementation without pass through the filter. Also I had been trying using a Bean instead of 'new', but the result is the same:

```
http.addFilterBefore(webAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

---

```
@Bean
public WebAuthenticationFilter webAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    WebAuthenticationFilter auth = new WebAuthenticationFilter();
    auth.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    auth.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return auth;
}
```

My custom filter is a extends of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and in the Override of the method attemptAuthentication this method is never call:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    tenant = request.getParameter("selectTenant");
    System.out.println("We are here WebAuthenticationFilter");
    request.getSession().setAttribute(TENANT_KEY, tenant);      
    return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that worked was injecting the HttpServletRequest class into my implementation of UserDetailsService so I take the new parameter from the request here.

```
public class myImpleentUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService (

@Autowired(required = false)
private HttpServletRequest request;

public UserDetail loadUserVyUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
    String myparameter = request.getParameter("myParameter");

    request.setAttribute("app-parameter", myparameter);

    user = userService.findById(username, myparameter);

...
}
```